# Spring Boot use components from a custom library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm separating my application to microservices.
Take a look at `AsyncConfiguration`:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration {
}
```

I noticed, that I will need that class in every microservice application. So I decided to create a library where all configurations will be located. But how can I connect this configuration to my microservice (I already connected the jar)? I also want to move my `@Aspect` and some `@Component` to the lib and connect them accordingly.

Comment: The same way as if it was in the application jar: classpath scanning, or configuration import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every app will have its own app configuration, each annotated with

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

In those you can import your common confgurations like

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@Import({AsyncConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

}